# Visual Studio 2015 automated tests with TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests

We are in the process of upgrading from TFS to 20**12** to TFS 20**15**, however the test team is ready to move to Visual Studio 2015 automated tests.  They currently have a number of VS 2012 automated tests they run in VS 2012 agents/controllers.

Given the configuration changes in Visual Studio automated test controllers/agents in Visual Studio 2015 (compared with VS 2012), will automated tests created in Visual Studio 2015 work with TFS 2012?

I know VS 2015 no longer utilizes test 'controllers' but relies on TFS 2015 to control automated tests.  If I read this [TFS compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents) article correctly: When you are using TFS 20**13**,  you must use VS 2013 test controllers and agents.  Or to put it another way, you cannot use VS Test agents against TFS 2013.  Is this correct?  And can I assume the same is correct for 2012?

To ask another way: If the test team **has** to use VS 2015 for automated tests now, can this be done without TFS 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Use TFS 2013 test controllers/agents with TFS 2015 if you need to maintain the existing capabilities for running tests out of MTM.